# Are all same: disjunct, sentence adverbs and conjunctive adverb

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

[This](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/) page says following:

> Some adverbs can modify entire sentences—unsurprisingly, these are called **sentence adverbs**. Common ones include *generally, fortunately, interestingly*, and *accordingly*. Sentence adverbs don’t describe one particular thing in the sentence—instead, they describe a general feeling about all of the information in the sentence. E.g. *Fortunately, we got there in time*.

[This](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/conjunctions.htm) page says following:

> The **conjunctive adverbs** such as *however, moreover, nevertheless, consequently*, as a result are used to create complex relationships between ideas.

[This](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/adverbs.htm) page says following:

> A **disjunct** frequently acts as a kind of evaluation of the rest of the sentence. Although it usually modifies the verb, we could say that it modifies the entire clause, too. Here are two more disjunctive adverbs:

- *Frankly*, Martha, I don't give a hoot.
- *Fortunately*, no one was hurt.

Does all three: sentence adverbs, conjunctive adverbs and disjunct mean the same?

Answer (score 1):

A **sentence adverb** is a kind of **disjunct**, but a **conjunctive adverb** is something different.

The third page you linked describes three types of adverbs: **adjuncts**, **disjuncts**, and **conjuncts**. It goes on to say that a conjunctive adverb is a special type of conjunct. The job of a conjunctive adverb is to link two clauses or sentences together and show how they are related to each other. In this sense, a conjunctive adverb is similar to a coordinating conjunction (*and*, *but*, *or*, etc.).

If a conjunctive adverb is joining two separate sentences, it will be at the start of the second sentence. If the two sentences are joined into one by a semicolon (**;**), the conjunctive adverb will be after the semicolon.

> I want to be a famous athlete. *However*, I'm fat and slow.
>
> I am very tired; *nevertheless*, I will finish my work before going to bed.
>
> I haven't eaten since breakfast. *Moreover*, there's no food in the house.

A disjunct does not connect two things together. It has a different job. It describes how the speaker or writer feels about the information in the other parts of the sentence. If the disjunct is at the start of the sentence, it is a sentence adverb.

> *Unfortunately*, Betty couldn't come to the party.

*(I said this because I like Betty.)*

> *Fortunately*, Betty couldn't come to the party.

*(I said this because I hate Betty.)*

> *Oddly*, Betty couldn't come to the party.

*(I said this because I am confused. I don't understand why this happened.)*